# What does $('[id$= represent in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am looking at some code and I see a lot of this:

```
$('[id$="txt"]').attr('excludeDirty', 'True');
```

I assume the "id$=txt" code is some method to tell jquery how to find a specific object in the DOM but I can't find any reference to back that up.

I did find that $() is the jquery selector so the code inside the parenthesis must be something to identify the selector, correct?

Thanks.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$('[id$="txt"]')
```

is the set of elements whose id ends with `txt`.

It uses the ["Attribute Ends With Selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

The syntax is obviously inspired from regular expressions : it's the same as

```
$('*').filter(function(){ return /text$/.test(this.id) });
```

There is the symmetric selector for elements whose an attribute starts with a text and it's logically

```
$('[attributename^="txt"]')
```

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about the 'ends with' selector http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

Comment: So essentially that means if the full string were: $('[id$="txtGreenHam"]') it would return an object with an id that ends with txtGreenHam. Is that correct?

Comment: All the elements that ends with txtGreenHam, yes

Answer (score 1):

If the equal sign is preceded by a dollar sign ($) then the selector will match the last characters of an attribute (such as a file extension).